# What is the difference between 'figure', 'graph' and 'drawings'?

Tags: word-choice

I like taking online IQ quizzes. Very commonly I see questions like this:

Which of the *figures* below the line of *drawings* best completes the series?

Sometimes it's like this:

Which of the *graphs* below the line of *drawings* best completes the series?

Are the words *figure*, *graph* and *drawings* above interchangeable with each other?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would say no, they are not interchangeable in general. A drawing is a kind of picture, not necessarily with any annotations or explanatory text. A picture that includes those things would be a figure or diagram. A graph is (although maybe as a mathematician/scientist I am biased!) some kind of data- or concept-driven plot involving patterns or numbers with at least one axis, such as a graph of the sine function (a wave) or a graph showing a company's budget over the last year.